# Sorting Table with Foreign Key Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Table(Geraete) in the View which also displays data from a Foreign Table by using the public Virtual Key Ort(Foreignkey to Table Orte) to access the other Table. This works fine, but my Problem is when i want to sort the Column of foreign Values the following Code snippet does not work:

```
//test.Sortcolumn(String Value of the Column name which should be sorted)

var pi = typeof(Geraete).GetProperty("test.SortColumn");

//movie.Typens is from Type List Geraete

movie.Typens = (from t in movie.Typens select t).OrderBy(x => pi.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

And yes this Snippet works for Columns of the same Entity Type Geraete.
In the View the values of the foreign Tables are easily accessable by using Ort.Columnname but this does also not work with the Code snippet above.

Comment: _does also not work_ This is not a helpful problem description!

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to traverse the navigation property it would be something like

```
x => 
{
  var o = x.GetType().GetProperty("test",x);
  var pi o.GetType().GetProperty("SortColumn");
  retrun pi.GetValue("SortColumn",o);
}
```

Comment: May you explain your Codesnippet a bit?

Comment: My Codesnippet after your Message:                                                 
      movie.Typens = (from t in movie.Typens select t).OrderBy(x =>
                          {
                              var o = x.GetType().GetProperty("test", x);
                              var pi = o.GetType().GetProperty("SortColumn");
                              return pi.GetValue("SortColumn", o);
                          }).ToList();       It doesnt work becaus x and o ErrorMessage Converting from System.Refelction.PropertyInfo in Object[] not possible